# How to deploy my app inside docker to ubuntu server

Tags: docker, apache, shell, ubuntu, docker-compose

I have an app running on `docker`. I am gonna deploy it to `ubuntu server`.

So I want that when i call domain or ip from browser `(ex: mydomain.com)` it displays my app in browser.

What configuration should I do in `docker or apache` conf. file?

Thank you!

Comment: `ubuntu server` is remote or is it same machine on which you are opening browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on many details you did not provide about your application.

In general you should write a **docker compose file** like this:

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: my-app
    image: ubuntu:latest
    hostname: myapp.com
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    entrypoint: sh -c /myapp-init-command.sh
    volumes:
      - /www/host/folder:/var/www/html
```

As you can see you should decide on which web server rely on.

For example, if you need of **apache** you should change **image** to a one which provides ready to use **apache**, or write a **docker file** which installs it into a stock **ubuntu server** like the one provided in my example.

Here an example of this...

**docker file**

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

ARG DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt update 
RUN apt install apache2 -y

ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["apachectl", "-D",  "FOREGROUND"]
```

**docker compose file**

```yaml
version: "3.5"

services:
  nginx:
    container_name: my-app
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myapp.dockerfile
    hostname: myapp.com
    ports:
      - 80:8080
    volumes:
      - /www/host/folder:/var/www/html
```

Comment: inside my remote server I have apach which is running. and it use 80 port. shoul i stop apache before? if yes then it doesnt work

Comment: I provided you a generic apache suitable solution which is on your own the role to develop it, depending on your own requirements. We could not develop a complete solution for you. It is out of scope of this forum.